# Code Review on Visual Studio 2013 Professional + TFS

Tags: code-review, visual-studio

Is there any code review extension for Visual Studio 2013 professional + TFS as source control, for free, that already has community support or still under development?

Comment: Have you looked under _Extensions and Updates_ in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I already search a lot. The only free, but abandoned, that I found (and I really don't know if it works with vs2013) is TeamReview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devart Review assistant is way better than code review tools built into VS and TFS. The most important feature that it has are iterative reviews - developers can add new changesets to the same review and restart it. And reviewer will still see his original comments, so he can check how they were addressed.

It is not free, but it is pretty cheap for small teams (10$ for 5 users).